# Phonegap Failure to install in Windows XP Pro 64 bit

Tags: cordova

I am noob in phonegap and also in java. I have the following errors during the phonegap installation. I have no proxy in my system.
My System is Windows XP prof 64 bit. I try all which I find here but have same errors
Turn of my router, antivirus, spyware progs - but errors are here.
http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap - try to get here in my browser and I can get in to only after sertificate installation to my browser

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'phonegap' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.11
3 info using node@v0.10.21
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'phonegap', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="phonegap" args=["phonegap",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'phonegap',
7 verbose parsed url   path: 'phonegap',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'phonegap' }
8 silly lockFile 10db903f-phonegap phonegap
9 verbose lock phonegap C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.TTT-D982C522DC0\Application Data\npm-cache\10db903f-phonegap.lock
10 silly lockFile 10db903f-phonegap phonegap
11 silly lockFile 10db903f-phonegap phonegap
12 verbose addNamed [ 'phonegap', '' ]
13 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
14 silly lockFile 3a6257f3-phonegap phonegap@
15 verbose lock phonegap@ C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.TTT-D982C522DC0\Application Data\npm-cache\3a6257f3-phonegap.lock
16 silly addNameRange { name: 'phonegap', range: '*', hasData: false }
17 verbose url raw phonegap
18 verbose url resolving [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/', './phonegap' ]
19 verbose url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
20 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 23:38:34
21 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
23 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 23:38:44
24 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
26 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 23:39:44
27 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
28 silly lockFile 3a6257f3-phonegap phonegap@
29 silly lockFile 3a6257f3-phonegap phonegap@
30 error network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
30 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
30 error network and is related to network connectivity.
30 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
30 error network
30 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
30 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
31 error System Windows_NT 5.2.3790
32 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs    \\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
33 error cwd C:\
34 error node -v v0.10.21
35 error npm -v 1.3.11
36 error syscall getaddrinfo
37 error code ENOTFOUND
38 error errno ENOTFOUND
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2):

So I try to find solution from my case. After some hours I understand that something in my network - probably my provider network. 
So I buy Private proxy and configure my npm via proxy

```
$ npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port
$ npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port
```

after that I install phonegap and cordova via that proxy.
Also same problem was in my Eclipse - updates - Window_preference_General_connection
I configure my proxy and updated my eclipse without any problem.
Do not forget restart your Eclipse - if not you have to update repository by hand - press RUN in every repository link.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Node.js is up to date and you are running the installer as an Administrator. Also make sure your eclipse, java, and android sdk are all 64 bit. To check your npm version type "node -v". The latest version is V0.10.21.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I try All for 64 bit. Install Java 8 for 32 and for 64 bit.Node -last version
Use administrator rights. But the same error - NPM error.
I do not use any proxy.
When I try to start update in my eclipse - always no repository founded. But when I start Android SDK - it is always find updates and install them.